# Xamarin googlePlayServiceComponent Analytics trackEvent doesnt work

Tags: google-analytics, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Google Analytics bundled in "Google Play Services" Component in Xamarin but my Track event doesnt work. Anyone know why?

```
private Tracker getTracker()
    {
         var googleAnalyticsInstance = GoogleAnalytics.GetInstance(((AndroidAppFeatures)App.AppFeatures).Activity.BaseContext);

        var tracker = googleAnalyticsInstance.NewTracker("UA-58482516-1");
        return tracker;

    }
    public  void TrackPageView(Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage viewModel)
    {
        var tracker = getTracker();
        tracker.SetScreenName(GetViewName(viewModel));
        var screenViewBuilder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder();
        tracker.Send(screenViewBuilder.Build());
    }

    public void TrackEvent(string category, string action, string label, long value = 0)
    {
        var tracker = getTracker();
        tracker.Send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().SetCategory(category).SetAction(action).SetLabel(label).SetValue(value).Build());
        tracker.Send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().Build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it didn't work for me either. After i added the config as xml it worked:
﻿

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxxxx</string>

    <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

    <string name="ga_logLevel">info</string>

    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

</resources>
```